# Database Management Odoo 10 Enterprise

Tags: odoo-10

I have just installed Odoo V10 Enterprise on an AWS server, everything was fine but I cannot access to the database manager screen. After

server_name/web/database/manager

I get 404:Page not found.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like, more of an Odoo V10 Enterprise error showing 404 for a given url path not related with AWS cloud platform issue. Can you check in Odoo V10 Enterprise forums and issue tracker for known issues

Answer (score 0):

I use Odoo E10 self-hosted.  The link I used to access database manager is the same as yours - but with the port included.

Obviously you may use a different port, http or https - depending on your setup, but here is the default.

> http://server_name:8069/web/database/manager